# How to make ToString() to return description Enum attribute if exist?

Tags: f#

I just found such question on C# and converted some code to F# but sadly it still being returning it's name. The question is: where is my mistake? or is there alternative ways to have some enum-like structure with optional string returnin when I want to get A.B.ToString()

Here is my try:

```
[<TypeConverter(typedefof<EnumToStringUsingDescription>)>]
type FontVariant =
    | [<Description("small-caps")>] smallCaps = 0
```

and

```
type EnumToStringUsingDescription() =
    inherit TypeConverter()
    override X.CanConvertFrom(context : ITypeDescriptorContext, sourceType : Type) =
        sourceType.Equals(typedefof<Enum>);
    override X.CanConvertTo(context : ITypeDescriptorContext, destinationType : Type) =
        (destinationType.Equals(typedefof<String>));
    override X.ConvertFrom(context : ITypeDescriptorContext, culture : System.Globalization.CultureInfo, value : obj) =
        base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    override X.ConvertTo(context : ITypeDescriptorContext, culture : System.Globalization.CultureInfo, value : obj, destinationType : Type) =
        if (not <| destinationType.Equals(typedefof<String>)) then
            raise <| new ArgumentException("Can only convert to string.", "destinationType");

        if (not <| value.GetType().BaseType.Equals(typedefof<Enum>)) then
            raise <| new ArgumentException("Can only convert an instance of enum.", "value");

        let name = value.ToString();
        let attrs = 
            value.GetType().GetField(name).GetCustomAttributes(typedefof<DescriptionAttribute>, false);
        if (attrs.Length > 0) then attrs.[0]
        else value
```

Comment: `printfn "%A"` will do most of this for far less effort.

Comment: @JohnPalmer No, it won't. It prints 'smallCaps'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. First, adding a TypeConverter will not influence `.ToString()`. 
Second, your conversion returns the attribute, not the description in the attribute. Here's a working function.

```
let getEnumDescription (value: Enum) =
   let typ = value.GetType()
   let name = value.ToString();
   let attrs = typ.GetField(name).GetCustomAttributes(typedefof<DescriptionAttribute>, false)
   if (attrs.Length > 0) then (attrs.[0] :?> DescriptionAttribute).Description :> obj
   else name :> obj
```

That said, certain libraries/frameworks will use a Type converter if available. Might look something like this. It may be that you have to implement ConvertFrom/CanConvertFrom as well, I'm not sure.

```
type EnumToStringUsingDescription() =
    inherit TypeConverter()
    override X.CanConvertTo(context : ITypeDescriptorContext, destinationType : Type) = (destinationType.Equals(typedefof<String>))
    override X.ConvertTo(context : ITypeDescriptorContext, culture : System.Globalization.CultureInfo, value : obj, destinationType : Type) =
       let typ = value.GetType()
       if (not <| typ.IsEnum) then raise <| new ArgumentException("Can only convert from enum.", "value");
       if (not <| typ.Equals typeof<string>) then raise <| new ArgumentException("Can only convert to string.", "destinationType");
       getEnumDescription (value :?> Enum)
```

Comment: true, my fault that it doesn't override ToString() is there another way to override ToString?

Comment: Sadly, for enums you can't.

Comment: @ℋeatђer - if you use a discriminated union you can override tostring

Comment: @ℋeatђer [Discriminated Unions (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Since, as Robert mentioned, enums cannot have members, and therefore you can't override `ToString`, you could do something like this, as a sort of compromise:

```
type FontVariant =
  | ``small-caps`` = 0
```

Then, `printf` works as desired:

```
printfn "%A" FontVariant.``small-caps``
```

```
> small-caps
```

Also, John's suggestion to use a discriminated union is a good one. They look just like enums, minus the numeric values:

```
type FontVariant =
  | SmallCaps
  override this.ToString() =
    match this with
    | SmallCaps -> "small-caps"
```

Use the `%O` format (`%A` will use Reflection and print the case name).

```
printfn "%O" FontVariant.SmallCaps
```

If you need the numeric value, as enums provide, you can define a property:

```
member this.Value =
  match this with
  | SmallCaps -> 0

printfn "%d" FontVariant.SmallCaps.Value
```